# Where to find “.ktr” file repositories?

Tags: pentaho, pdi

I am doing research using Pentaho/PDI for my masters. So in order to develop it, I need an amount of reliable “.ktr” files to analyze them. For that reason, I am coming to you so you can share with me some repositories that contain those files or information about some open source projects that use them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are asking for source code that developers have created to manage their data, so I don't think you are going to find a lot of public repositories with that source code.

PDI is mostly used to "move" and transform data, so the PDI files created are going to show about the content of the data, companies are not going to share that unless the data the PDI files are managing is public.

Unless you find some university researchers using PDI to treat the data in their studies, or teachers of masters related to data science using PDI in the subjects they teach, I don't think there's going to be much around.